# Heading with different formatted text standing next to it

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to make heading with different formated text next to it, in my case Name and year, e.g. name of an author and his birthdate and the date of his death. Something like this:

[image]

And I also want to have the first paragraph without any indent as it should be.

1. `\subsection{Edgar Allan Poe} {\large(1809--1849)} \\
   Some text...`
   While there is `[runin]` setting with titlesec package.

This is kinda awful solution so I was thinking about something different.

2. `\subsection{Edgar Allan Poe \normalfont (1809--1849)}
   Some text...`
   While there is not `[runin]` setting with titlesec package and used \titlespacing* for first paragraph without indent as needed.

In this case I don't like messy looking structure list so I don't think this is the best solution for my problem.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I also don't want to have the different text in ToC (table of contents) so the second option doesn't work well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean by ‘without an alignment’? The first paragraph should start at the left margin, i.e. without paragraph indent?

Comment: Yes, that's is, I was thinking about paragraph indent, I'm sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I guess the second solution works. What exactly  don't you like?

Comment: It works but in structure list it doesn't look nice to me when there's \normalfont everywhere, so I've wanted to know if there is better option to do that.

Comment: You might try to patch the `\subsection` command so that it can accept a second optional argument. However I'm not sure it's worth the effort. Perhaps simply define a `\dates` command which  types its content in normal font. At least it would semantically more satisfactory.